# Como hacer un update checkbox mostrados en modal php y mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery

Tengo un tabla llamada `anamnesis_veterinario` que tiene varios campos, pero al registrar una fila a la vez tengo que registrar un checkbox multiple.

Todo ok hasta ahi por que cree otra tabla con la relacion checkbox y el id de `anamnesis`, y atrapo el `last inser id` y con un foreach registro todos los checkbox marcados.

Luego en el boton editar llamo al modal y muestro los datos correspondientes `ayudandome` de `onclick` y pasandole luego en jquery los valores a cada de uno de sus `val()`.

Todo ok pero en la seccion donde debe aparecerme los checkbox ya seleccionados no tengo idea como hacerlo. He intentado guardar el `id` de `anamnesis` en una sesion al abrir el modal pero nada. He intentado pasar el `id` por post con ajax pero no me lo trae.

No se como hacer con puro jquery si alguien a tenido una experiencia similar o me puedra ayudar se lo agradeceria mucho dejare fotos por este medio.

En esta imagen traigo los datos de cada registro ayudandome de jquery
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aca estoy traendo manualmente los checkbox seleccionados poniendole yo 4 como id
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el formulario de registro de anamnesis y asi son los checkbox traidos desde una tabla , al registrar tengo otra tabla que los uno donde guardo id_anamnesis,id_checkbox_anamnesis
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el fragmento de codigo donde intento reemplazar el 4 por el id de anamnesis pero no he logrado manera.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He itentado mandar el id por ajax recibiendo el post en anemnesis-veterinario.php pero no llega o quiza estoy haciendo algo mal , por otro lado estoy trabajando con url amigable por eso en la URL no pongo .php , tambien en el anemnesis-veterinario.php pregunte por una llegada post y no me muestra nada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Los checkbox se envían al servidor sólo cuando su propiedad `checked == true`.
Si querés que se envíen cuando no estén seleccionados tendrías que agregarlos manualmente cuando hacés el request (teniendo en cuenta que estás modificando el comportamiento estandard, y que puede causar conflictos con otros scripts que reciban esas requests).

No estoy seguro si soluciona tu problema. Deberías tratar de mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta, por ejemplo, mostrando el código en vez de imágenes.